# Activating certain PHP code before a section of the page is Created

Tags: php, html

I am working with an HTML webpage connected to a database and using PHP. I have in a div at the top a variable that doesn't get properly set until some PHP later in the document. Is there a way to make the div build after the later PHP, but still be where it should be at the top of the page?

Here's the code that uses the variables

```
<div id="HeaderRight">         
        <div id="HeaderRight">        
        <?php        
        echo '<a href="../Cart/index.php" class="header">
        <img src="../Images/shoppingcart.gif" height="18" width="127"     border="0" align="ABSMIDDLE" /> Contains '.$_SESSION["num_items"].' Items</a>'
        ?>
     </div>
```

Here's the code that sets the variables

```
<?php

echo '<TABLE WIDTH="100%" BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" ALIGN = "RIGHT" BORDER = "1">';
echo '<TR BGCOLOR = "818996" HEIGHT = "25"><TD>Product</TD><TD>Availability</TD>               <TD>Qty</TD><TD>Price</TD><TD>Total</TD></TR>';

$strTotalPrice = 0;

for ($i=0; $i<$_SESSION['num_products']; $i++) {

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ProductCode = '".$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['name']."'";

$rsProd = mysql_query($strSQL)
    or die($db_name . " : " . $strSQL . " : " . mysql_error());

$rowProd = mysql_fetch_array($rsProd);


$strSQLDetails = "SELECT * FROM pagedetails WHERE Category = '".$rowProd["Category"]."'";
$rsDetails = mysql_query($strSQLDetails)
    or die($db_name . " : " . $strSQLDetails . " : " . mysql_error());

$rowDetails = mysql_fetch_array($rsDetails);
// End Of "Retrieve Desired Record Set"

echo ' <TR HEIGHT = "' .$rowProd["ThumbnailHeight"]. '" ><TD style="vertical-align:middle"><img src="../'.$rowProd["Department"].'/Images/'.$rowProd["ProductCode"].'_sm.jpg" align = "left" border="0" height = "'.$rowProd["ThumbnailHeight"].'" width="100" hspace="25" />
      <br><a href = "../Products/Products.php?PageID='.$rowDetails["PageID"].'" >'.$rowProd["ProductName"].'</a>
       </TD>';

$strAvailability = "";
$strQuantity = 0;
if($rowProd["Stock"] < $_SESSION["cart"][$i]["qty"]){
    $strAvailability = "Only " .$rowProd["Stock"]. " in Stock, Quantity Changed";
    $strQuantity = $rowProd["Stock"];
    $_SESSION["cart"][$i]["qty"] = $rowProd["Stock"];
}
else{
    $strAvailability = "In Stock";
    $strQuantity = $_SESSION["cart"][$i]["qty"];
}


echo '<TD ALIGN = "center">'.$strAvailability.'</TD>';
echo '<TD ALIGN = "center">
<input type="text" name="txtQuantity" size="2" maxlength="2" value ='.$strQuantity.'>';
echo '<form action="index.php?=?product='.$rowProd["ProductCode"].'&quantity=1" method="post"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"> 
</form> 
</TD>';

$strPrice = $rowProd["RegPrice"] * $strQuantity;
$strTotalPrice += $strPrice;

echo '<TD ALIGN = "center">$'.$rowProd["RegPrice"].'.00</TD>';
echo '<TD ALIGN = "center">$'.$strPrice.'.00</TD></TR>';
//echo '( <a href=index.php?product=' . $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['name'] . '&quantity=1>+</a> )';  
}
```

Comment: Problems like this are why I separate the logic and the views.  Run *all* of your PHP code before rendering the HTML.

Comment: Set the variable before displaying anything...

Also, post your code.

Answer (score 0):

As Rocket Hazmat points out, it is a good idea to run all of your PHP code before rendering the HTML. Without rewriting your current code, you can achieve this with some [output buffering](https://www.php.net/ob_start):

```
<?
// add this block
function firstDiv() {
  ob_start();
?>

<div id="HeaderRight">         
  ... <? echo $_SESSION["num_items"]; ?> ...
</div>

<?
 // ... and this block
   $_SESSION["firstDiv"] = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
} // end of firstDiv
?>
```

and the same with the rest of your page

```
<?
function restOfYourPage() {
  ob_start();
?>

<TABLE> ... <? $_SESSION["num_items"] = 666; ?> ... </TABLE>

<?
  $_SESSION["restOfYourPage"] = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
} // end of restOfYourPage
?>
```

Then you can run the php code in reverse order, but display it in normal order:

```
<?
 restOfYourPage();
 firstDiv();
 echo $_SESSION["firstDiv"];
 echo $_SESSION["restOfYourPage"];
?>
```